# Starting a new thread blocks the main application

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I am trying to use a new thread for in order to do some data request and processing from some websites but when I start the thread in the MainWindow the GUI is not displayed (I see nothing).

Here is part of the relevant code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(&shopItems);
    QThread thread;
    thread.setObjectName("thread");

    a.address = ui->address;
    a.Filter = ui->filter;
    a.browsers = ui->browsers;
    a.excel = ui->excel;
    a.shopItems = &shopItems;
    a.moveToThread(&thread);
    connect(ui->dataPull, SIGNAL(clicked()), &a, SLOT (pull_data()));
    connect(ui->excel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(export_to_excel()));
    connect(ui->stop, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Stop()));
    //thread.start();
    //thread.wait();
}
```

I think this happens because when I use thread.start() the eventloop is transferred to the new thread.

Any Idea how to start a new another thread while making the main thread running and responsive?

Comment: Your `QThread` has local scope within the `MainWindow` constructor and will be destroyed as soon as the constructor completes.  Try making the `QThread` a member of `MainWindow` instead.

Comment: From [the `QThread` destructor reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#dtor.QThread): "Deleting a running QThread ... will result in a program crash". So if you start the thread and don't wait for it to finish (and waiting will stop all of the program) then your program will crash. Indeed, define the thread as a member of the `MainWindow` class instead.

Comment: Yes I made QThread a member of MainWindow and it is working